# Rails - migrations - change_column_default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I wish to change the default of an integer in my database via migrations

```
class ChangeColumnDefault < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column_default(:persons, :age, 0)
  end
end
```

I have also tried:

```
class ChangeColumnDefault < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        change_column_default(:persons, :age, 0)
      end
    end
```

And I just run the migration by:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=20120822182554_change_column_default.rb
```

No errors are displayed in the terminal, and i can see no changes in my schema.rb

Any ideas/hints??

Comment: Please post the output of the terminal when you run this command.  Roll it back first, then rerun it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use just `rake db:migrate VERSION=20120822182554`

and where is table name? :)

Comment: Yes persons is the table name-and running rake db:migrate VERSION=20120822182554 makes no difference

Comment: try `change_column_default('persons', 'age', 0)`

Comment: @Vetal4eg same problem. `change_column_default` not working. I am using `postgresql` and I checked the db. There is no modifier

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out, it worked. It seems like your table would be :people though and not :persons. Also it make the most since to me to use 'def up' and 'def down'.

Answer (score 0):

So lets say you want to set default value to nil and have created the following file `db/migrate/20200820171322_change_default_field_on_table.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ChangeDefaultFieldOnTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]

  def up
    change_column_default(:table, :column_name, nil)
  end

end
```

That should pretty much do the trick, in case it helps!